# How to use the results of the previous query in the next query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As a result of this query I have a table:

```
select i.id, o.[name]  from Item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o on o.[name]='I' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(20))
where o.name is not null
```

[image]

Now I need to use the result of this table in the next query:

```
select PriceListItem.ProductExternalId, @id.Id, @id.FriendlyName, @id.BriefWiki,
    [PriceListItem].[ProductExternalDesc]
from [@id]
inner join [Product]  on Product.ItemId = @name and Product.InstanceId = @id.ID
inner join [PriceListItem]  on Product.ID = PriceListItem.ProductId
```

instead of '@id' I should use data from the table with name= id, and instead of '@name' I should use data from the table with name= name

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on SQL 2K8 you can use a CTE:

```
-- You may need a ; before WITH as in ;WITH
WITH FirstQuery AS (
  select i.id, o.[name]  from Item i
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o on o.[name]='I' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(20))
  where o.name is not null
)
select PriceListItem.ProductExternalId,
       FQ.Id,
       -- Neither of these are in your FirstQuery so you can not use them
       -- @id.FriendlyName, @id.BriefWiki,
       [PriceListItem].[ProductExternalDesc]
from FirstQuery FQ
     inner join [Product] on Product.ItemId = FQ.name
                         and Product.InstanceId = FQ.ID
     inner join [PriceListItem]  on Product.ID = PriceListItem.ProductId;
```

From the queries alone it's tough to tell how you plan to `JOIN` them, but this will allow you to make use of the first query in the subsequent one.

Looks like you have some syntax errors in your second query - `@id.id`?

Comment: I don't understand how to use the first query in this script and from where I can get my parameters? can you explain?

Comment: I dont have error I have just change the name with parameters that I don't know how to get from the first query

Comment: Is `@id` actually a table variable?

Comment: no, instead of '@id' I should use data from the table with name= id, and instead of @name I should use data from the table with name= name

Comment: It has an error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'I451' to data type int.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL way, works in most RDBMS

```
select PriceListItem.ProductExternalId, @id.Id, @id.FriendlyName, @id.BriefWiki,
    [PriceListItem].[ProductExternalDesc]
from 
    (
    select i.id, o.[name]  from Item i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o on o.[name]='I' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(20))
    where o.name is not null
    )
    X
    inner JOIN
    [@id] ON X.id = @id.id --change here as needed
    inner join [Product]  on Product.ItemId = @name and Product.InstanceId = @id.ID
    inner join [PriceListItem]  on Product.ID = PriceListItem.ProductId*
```

Comment: From how I've read the question, the subselect is not supposed just to be added to the query, it should go *instead of* `@id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.id, o.[name]  from Item i
into @temp_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o on o.[name]='I' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(20))
where o.name is not null
```

Now you can use @temp_table as you want :)